# How to show if $a$$\leq$$b_1$, for every $b_1>b$, then $a$$\leq$$b$ where a,b$\epsilon$R?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Not positive on the proper approach to this problem.

My first thought:

$a $ $\leq$ $b_1$ means either $a=b_1$ or $a<b_1$. 
Should it broken up into cases?

---

Second attempt: 
Assume, to the contrary, $a > b$, then let $b_1$= $(a+b)/2$. It follows that, $a > b_1 > b$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, $a\leq b$. $ \Box$$ $

Comment: I think you meant to assume that these $a,b,c$ are real numbers.

Comment: Yes I did, thank you @hardmath

Comment: Let c = b + epsilon , epsilon > 0, then let epsilon go to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be a real number. If there is a real $b$ such that $a \leq c$ for every real $c > b$ and $a > b$, then there is a real $c$ such that $b < c < a;$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

What would happen if, to the contrary, $a>b$?

Comment: @19059: Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a mistake in the question.  Play with each case 
a = c and a 
Note- my suggestion is not proof by contradiction which assumes the conclusion false, then derives a contradiction => the assumption is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If $a>b$, then let $c:=\frac{a+b}{2}$, and you have $a> c >b$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore $a \leq b$.

Comment: Thanks so much @marcoflores, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you changed the letters on us, which creates confusion with existing answers.  The question I'm answering is

> How to show if a≤b1, for every b1>b, then a≤b where a,bϵR?

Let a=b1,  then by the hypothesis    a > b.
but this contradicts the desired conclusion a≤b

Notice I assumed nothing except for a specific case allowed in the original statement.  So as given the theorem is false.  (A single counterexample can prove an entire theorem false)

Is there something I missed?

Comment: "Is there something I missed?" Yes.

Comment: Andres, that's not helpful- what did I miss?

Comment: A quantifier, "for every".

Comment: Ok.  I see it now.

Comment: It should be the same regardless if I use b1 or c, they are just symbols. I just wanted to let it match my text. @nickalh